# Line breaks are lost in macro parameters of SAS

Tags: parameters, sas, macros

I want to transfer text containing line breaks from a SAS table to an external database table (via ODBC).
I use a macro variable as a buffer. Using a macro I insert the text into the table
of the remote database. The problem is that the line breaks in the text are lost,
if I pass the text as parameter to the macro.
How can I keep the line breaks?

```
%macro dbinsert (id=,text=);
/*
   Macro for inserting text into table of second database.
   For test purposes, odbc table replaced with SAS table.
   Issue: line breaks will be lost. How can i keep the line breaks?

   Original Code:
      proc sql;
         CONNECT TO ODBC (DSN="mydb");
         EXEC (update mytable
            set text= "&text."
            where id = &id.;
            ) BY ODBC;
      quit;
*/
   proc sql noprint;
       update x2
       set text = "&text."
       where id = &id.;
   quit;

%mend dbinsert;

%macro main;

/* Initialize SAS table. Just for test purposes. */
data x1;
   text="Hello Martin how are you?"; output;
   text="Thank you I am fine!"; output;
   text="And how are you?"; output;
run;

/* Read content from SAS table into macro variable (text1). The content is separated via line breaks 0D0A. */
proc sql noprint;
   select text into :text1 separated by '0D0A'x from x1;
quit;

/* Initialize table in second database. Just for test purposes. */
data x2;
   length id 8 text $200;
   id=1; text="111"; output;
   id=2; text="222"; output;
run;

%dbinsert(id=2,text=&text1.);

%mend main;
%main;
```

Comment: Why not just write the macro assuming that the parameter value is already quoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the quotes required to convert your macro variable's value into valid code you can just write the macro to assume that the value is already valid syntax to be included into the generated code.  Then the SQL syntax is just:

```
set text = &text.
```

Then you can if you need to add any syntax that your remote system uses to specify special characters in a string

```
%dbinsert (id=,text='ABC'||byte(13)||'XYZ')
```

If you have an existing macro variable and you want to enclose it in single quotes you can use a data step to preserve any special characters.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('text',quote(symget('text'),"'"));
run;
```

Note using a data step will limit you to 32K byte strings instead of the 64k bytes limit that macro variables can hold.

Answer (score 0):

Macro does not support non-printable characters.

From documentation

> **[Getting Started with the Macro Facility](http://%20https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1ccprwibo8gvqn1q6zinvjlzuut.htm&locale=en#!)**
> ...
> The SAS macro language is a string-based language. It does not support the use of hexadecimal character constants.
>
> ---
>
> Note: The SAS macro language does not support using hexadecimal values to specify non-printable characters.
>
> ---

and

> **[Macro Variables](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1jgr545j3yz29n1uic9qlvlrzo4.htm&locale=en#!)**
> ...
> Macro variable values have a maximum length of 65,534 characters. The length of a macro variable is determined by the text assigned to it instead of a specific length declaration. So its length varies with each value that it contains. Macro variables contain only character data. However, the macro facility has features that enable a variable to be evaluated as a number when it contains character data that can be interpreted as a number. The value of a macro variable remains constant until it is specifically changed. Macro variables are independent of SAS data set variables.
>
> ---
>
> Note: Only printable characters should be assigned to macro variables. Non-printable values that are assigned to macro variables can cause unpredictable results.
>
> ---

**Possible alternative**

You know about `EXEC` and pass through -- Good!

Consider using SQL to construct the **source code for a string expression** that concatenates string literals.  The expression would contain source code utilizing character functions native to the remote data base.  The `DBINSERT` macro would have to be modified to deal with the parameter now containing an expression.

Again, macro converts non-printable characters to space, so if the data values in `x1.text` contain embedded CRLF, they would not be present in the constructed expression.

Example:

**Important:** **DO NOT USE THIS VERSION OF DBINSERT WITH ANY INPUT SUPPLIED BY AN UNTRUSTED USER or WEB INPUT**.  Codegen from data values is a vector for SQL injection or code injection.

```
%macro dbinsert (id=,expression=);
   proc sql noprint;
       update x2
       set text = &expression
       where id = &id.;
   quit;
%mend dbinsert;

data x1;
   text="Hello Martin how are you?"; output;
   text="Thank you I am fine!"; output;
   text="And how are you?"; output;
run;

/*
 * CONSTRUCT SOURCE CODE FOR AN EXPRESSION THAT CONCATENTATES STRING LITERALS
 * (also known as codegen short for code generator)
 */
proc sql noprint;
  select 
    quote(trim(text)) 
    into :text1 
    separated by '||byte(13)||byte(10)||' 
    from x1;

data x2;
   length id 8 text $200;
   id=1; text="111"; output;
   id=2; text="222"; output;
run;

options mprint;
%dbinsert(id=2,expression=&text1.);
%symdel text1;

title;
ods html style=monospace;
proc print data=x2; where id=2; 
proc print data=x2; where id=2; format text $HEX400.;
proc print data=x2; where id=2; 
  var text / style=[asis=true];
run;
ods html close;
```

Log showing codegen in action when `DBINSERT` invoked.

```
634  %dbinsert(id=2,expression=&text1.);
MPRINT(DBINSERT):   proc sql noprint;
MPRINT(DBINSERT):   update x2 set text = "Hello Martin how are you?"||byte(13)||byte(10)||"Thank
you I am fine!"||byte(13)||byte(10)||"And how are you?" where id = 2;
NOTE: 1 row was updated in WORK.X2.
```

Examine the result.  SAS *ViewTable* renders non-printables as space, but the control characters are there in the data values.

Image of result in viewer

[image]

Same result in ODS HTML, second table shows text value when HEX formatted.  Third table shows the viewing of control characters as interpreted by `ODS HTML` when style option `ASIS=YES` is in effect.

[image]